# How to convert plain text to html and assign it to an <li> in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, bulletedlist

I have a string with html content as follows:

```
string eg = "hi..how <b>are</b> you?"
```

I am assigning this string value to the text property of a bulleted list as follows:

```
lst.Text = eg;
```

The purpose is to display "are" in bold. But currently it displays the string as it is. What property of the bulleted list is to be used to render the html controls in the string?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What are you using for the Web server?

Comment: What is `lst`?  Is this ASP.NET webforms? MVC?  I assume webforms but no real context here.

Comment: @EliGassert My guess is [BulletedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.bulletedlist.aspx)

Comment: @Romoku Unlikely - attempting to set the [Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.bulletedlist.text.aspx) of that will throw a NotSupportedException. From the docs: `The Text property is set internally based on the selected list item in the BulletedList control. If you set the Text property directly, a NotSupportedException exception is thrown.`

Comment: Hi...it's a ListItem inside a bulleted list..i'm setting the 
Text property of ListItem....i'm using asp dotnet webforms

Comment: Ok. That is something that you should put in a tag and in the Question body.

Comment: i'm sorry for not mentioning it first

Comment: That's ok. We just need context to answer the question properly.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use an  *Repeater* instead of a *Bulleted List* as bulleted list
doesn't support HTML for its ListItems

Similar questions can help you

[Programmatically adding a hyperlink to a bulleted list that IS NOT DisplayMode=Hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13080120/programmatically-adding-a-hyperlink-to-a-bulleted-list-that-is-not-displaymode-h)

[Customized bulleted list items in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097916/customized-bulleted-list-items-in-asp-net)

And this channel9 msdn page

http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/257894-aspnet-BulletedList-list-item-with-HTML-

Quoting from above

> Try using a Repeater. The BulletedList unfortunately doesn't support
>   HTML for its ListItems.

Markup

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate><ul></HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate><li><span class="label">Test</span> <%# Container.DataItem %></li></ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate></ul></FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

C#

```
Repeater1.DataSource = items;
Repeater1.DataBind();
```